# Crypting CSSMERR_DLL_MISSING_VALUE when trying to sign code for iPhone device

Tags: iphone, codesign

I have some code which runs fine in simulator, but when I try to build for iPhone, I get a cryptic error:

```
CodeSign /Users/.../myApp.app (1 error)
error: CSSMERR_DL_MISSING_VALUE
```

That's it. No other references.

Sounds like it's something about my code signing privileges, but what exactly? My private key, certificate and provisioning profile should be OK, but this happens with all apps, so it's not app specific. I tried reinstalling the provisioning profile, but to no avail. What should I do to get rid of this error and make code sign work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is a weird one:

I had a smart card reader connected, with a smart card with a private key and certificate on it, that I use for some signing and authentication operations. It has nothing to do with Xcode, but apparently this smartcard confused Keychain enough to spit out this error. Disconnected the card reader and signing works again as expected.